# Miscellaneous Problem Chapter I ex.22 on G.H.Hardy's book "A course of pure mathematics"

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, rational-numbers, rationality-testing

If all the values of x and y given by
$$
ax^{2}+2hxy+by^{2}=1, a'x^{2}+2h'xy+b'y^2=1
$$
(where $a, h, b, a', h', b'$ are rational) are rational, then
$$
(h-h')^2 - (a-a')(b-b'), (ab'-a'b)^2+4(ah'-a'h)(bh'-b'h)
$$
are both squares of rational numbers. (Math. Trip. 1899)

Note: the first case is trivial, the second is more difficult, ill be granted if someone could tell me from where Hardy and collaborators get this miscellaneous problems, to be specific the problems with the reference (Math. Trip. yyyy).

Comment: They come from the Mathematical Tripos.

Comment: ... and the Mathematical Tripos were end of year exams sat by undergraduate students at the University of Cambridge. Hardy was a professor at Trinity College, Cambridge and will have devised many questions in the Mathematical Tripos exams (although 1899 was shortly before he graduated).

Comment: @gandalf61: Hardy was a staunch hater of tripos and did his best to get rid of it. He believed that it ruined mathematical education of England and that was one of the reasons England was much behind rest of Europe.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, but before that he was a Tripos examiner: “the Mathematical Tripos is an institution of which I have an extensive and intimate knowledge ... I was a candidate in both parts of it, I took my degree on it, I have examined in it repeatedly under both the old regulations and the new” https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Extras/Hardy_Tripos/

Comment: Are you expecting a solution to the problem here or just trying to get the source of such questions (as mentioned in Note)?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  i am expecting a solution, the first expression was trivial as i mentioned, but the second is my doubt, if i can get the solution i will publish it.

Comment: @SAULROJAS You can find a solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2537743/show-that-ab-ab2-4ah-ahbh-bh-is-a-perfect-square?rq=1).